# for loop for nltk stopwords goes to infinity

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
import nltk as nt

txt="The latest version of Anaconda comes with Python 3.8. But sometimes you need to use an earlier release. With Anaconda, the preferred way to use a previous version of Python is to create a separate conda environment for each project."

word_tok=nt.word_tokenize(txt)
stopWords=nt.corpus.stopwords.words("english")
print(word_tok)

wordClear=[]
for i in word_tok: # infinity loop
      if i not in stopWords:
        word_tok.append(i)
```

what is the problem?

I see always up stated form but my project's this form is infinity loop but

```
for i in word_tok:
  print(i)
```

This for did'nt infinity loop.

Comment: You mean to append to `wordClear`, not `word_tok`.

Comment: yeah ::( soryy, i two hours work this problem and didnt see!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import nltk as nt

txt="The latest version of Anaconda comes with Python 3.8. But sometimes you need to use an earlier release. With Anaconda, the preferred way to use a previous version of Python is to create a separate conda environment for each project."

word_tok=nt.word_tokenize(txt)
stopWords=nt.corpus.stopwords.words("english")
print(word_tok)

wordClear=[]
for i in word_tok: # infinity loop
      if i not in stopWords:
        # Do you wantthis?
        wordClear.append(i)
```

You are updating the array `word_tok` and dynamically add new i's. So it might keep on increasing and never end.

Comment: To be even more specific than it might keep increasing forever: if there's even one word in `word_tok` that isn't in `stopWords` it *will* be an infinite loop.

Comment: but this form always use. ex :  https://pythonspot.com/nltk-stop-words/  i try set(stopwords) didnt. work.

Comment: But pay atention that they update different array, not the one iterating

Comment: my mistake i tried for how many hours and i couldn't see it escaped my attention